# Adobe Animate Javascript TypeError mystery - can't solve

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate

I'm developing a simple application in Animate running in Canvas mode. It has a number of movie clip buttons on the stage with instance names 'p1', 'p2',....up to 'p19'. Clicking a button will cause another movie clip 'partOverlay' to be visible and go to frame on its timeline.

Everything works fine when only p1 through p13 are coded as shown below.  But p14 gives a TypeError: this.p14 is undefined. So do the other instances after p13.  I triple checked the names and syntax and everything looks OK.  When I copy the p14 button and code to a new Animate document it works OK.

I've spent a few hours on this searching online and testing and am at my wits end. Any help is appreciated.

sample code:

```
this.p13.cursor = "pointer";
this.p13.addEventListener("click", GoToPartFrame2.bind(this, "p13"));

this.p14.cursor = "pointer";
this.p14.addEventListener("click", GoToPartFrame2.bind(this, "p14"));

function GoToPartFrame2(view)
{   
    this.partOverlay.gotoAndStop(view);
    this.partOverlay.visible=true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered something weird.  All of the buttons are instances of a single button that I cloned and gave new instance names to create new buttons. I had different sets of buttons on three different timeline keyframes - all copies of the original button. When I commented out the code for the button with the TypeError and tested the file, somehow that button still had a listener working on it and would actuate a function from some other button on another keyframe. Both buttons had unique instance names which is all the more puzzling.

I assumed there was a name conflict between the internal name of the button and the instance name I gave it. Animate was disregarding the instance name and applying another internal object name. On a hunch I created new original buttons for each keyframe. In other words - each keyframe has a set of buttons cloned from a unique master button for that keyframe. Now everything works as it should.  Kind of stupid and unintuitive that it should work this way... the program should consider the unique instance names that I apply as the prime identifiers for the objects regardless of what keyframe the cloned button is on.  Lots of wasted time.